# C# SqlConnection Opening

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio

I don't know why my SQL connection dosen't open.  My text is exactly like in a book. The problem is with conn.Open(), and i don't know why, that is the same with my book. Thanks.

using Visual studio 2010 express.

```
 private void RegisterBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string  connstring =
            @"server = .\sqlexpress;
            Database = Database1.mdf;
            trusted_connection=True;
            AttachDBFileName=  D:\Work\C#\DatabaseLoginPassProj\DatabaseLoginPassProj\Database1.mdf";

            SqlConnection conn = null;
            SqlDataReader reader = null;


        string InsertInDB = @" INSERT INTO UserPass
                                     (User , Pass)
                                    Values
                                     ('" + UserBox.Text + "', '" + PassBox.Text + "') ";
        try
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection (connstring);
            conn.Open();

        } catch

        { MessageBox.Show("Error Opening Connection"); }

        try
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(InsertInDB, conn);
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Close();

        }
        catch { MessageBox.Show("ExecureReader Error"); }














    }
```

Comment: It might not like the newlines in the connection string. Also, "doesn't open" isn't very helpful. You should include what happens in your question. Does it throw an exception? What's the exception that it throws?

Comment: what error or exception you get? do you really have the `Database1.mdf` file in disk?

Comment: I recive the Error Opening Connection. from the try and catch

Comment: Change `catch { MessageBox.Show("Error Opening Connection");}` to `catch(Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show("Error Opening Connection"); }` and report back what the message is in `ex` and the exception type. As what you have now is bad (never do this!!), you swallow the exception and do not know a thing about it. Either handle it so you can recover or do catch it. If you want to log that's fine but log the details of the Exception object and then rethrow it with `throw;` (**not** `throw ex;`)

Comment: start replacing your catch blocks with something like: `catch(Exception ex){Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());throw;}`; you can get a lot of information about what went wrong.

Comment: Does `sqlexpress` instance exist on your system? may be sql server instance name is different on your system.

Comment: I changed that, i recive  Error Opening Connection

Comment: @Mihai Change your messagebox call to `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);`

Comment: Changed that """"  Unable to open the physical file "D:\Work\C#\DatabaseLoginPassProj\DatabaseLoginPassProj\Database1.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".
Cannot attach the file 'D:\Work\C#\DatabaseLoginPassProj\DatabaseLoginPassProj\Database1.mdf' as database 'Database1.mdf'.  ""

Comment: Start with this: [Google - How to handle exceptions c#](https://www.google.com/#q=how+to+handle+exceptions+c%23)

Comment: Now you know why it doesn't open: access is denied.

Comment: Yes, thanks i solved the problem. I ran VS as Administrator and problem solved thanks guys

Comment: @Mihai In the future, please do the necessary work of gathering the exception details so that you do not have to be prompted for them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your connection string with this:

```
string  connstring =
    @"server=.\sqlexpress;
    Database=Database1.mdf;
    trusted_connection=True;
    AttachDBFileName=D:\Work\C#\DatabaseLoginPassProj\DatabaseLoginPassProj\Database1.mdf";
```

Also make sure to run VS as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to open a SQL Express database or an Access database?
If Access database, try something similar to the following:

```
string  connstring = @"Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0; AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\AppNameDb.mdf; Integrated Security=SSPI; User Instance=True"
```